# How to ETL multiple files using Scriptella?

Tags: etl, scriptella

I am having multiple log files 1.csv,2.csv and 3.csv generated by a log report.
I want to read those files and parse them concurrently using Scriptella.

Answer (score 3):

Scriptella does not provide parallel job execution out of the box. Instead you should use a job scheduler provided by an operating system or a programming environment (e.g. run multiple ETL files by submitting jobs to an ExecutorService).

Here is a working example to import a single file specified as a system property:

**ETL file**:

```
<!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd">
<etl>
    <connection id="in" driver="csv" url="$input"/>
    <connection id="out" driver="text"/>
    <query connection-id="in">
        <script connection-id="out">
            Importing: $1, $2
        </script>
    </query>
</etl>
```

**Java code to run files in parallel:**

```
//Imports 3 csv files in parallel using a fixed thread pool
public class ParallelCsvTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws EtlExecutorException, MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        for (int i=1;i<=3;i++) {
            //Pass a name as a parameter to ETL file, e.g. input<i>.csv
            final Map<String,?> map = Collections.singletonMap("input", "input"+i+".csv");
            EtlExecutor executor = EtlExecutor.newExecutor(new File("parallel.csv.etl.xml").toURI().toURL(), map);
            service.submit((Callable<ExecutionStatistics>)executor);
        }
        service.shutdown();
        service.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Tu run this example create 3 csv files input1.csv, input2.csv and input3.csv and put them in the current working directory. Example of the CSV file:

```
Level, Message
INFO,Process 1 started
INFO,Process 1 stopped
```

Comment: @ejboy- suppose i want to pass input1.csv from command prompt in windows then how would i go for it>

Comment: You can use the "args" variable in the example. It contains cmd line arguments.

Comment: can plz give it in detail by writting the command line code? :)

Comment: what i meant is that i dont want to use the java code, rather i want to run scriptella from command line and specify the raw filenames in comman line itself

Comment: You cannot run ETL files in parallel just by using Scriptella command line interface. You either need the example code shown above(possibly modified to accept list of names) or use some external tool, for instance Apache Ant [Parallel Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html)

Comment: Suppose i want to specify a single filename in command line. Then?

Comment: This is old, but you can specify wildcards for the command line launcher and it will process all the files in what appears to be sorted order.  I use *.etl.xml to run everything in my project, and I number the files in the order in which they should be run.